# ClusterManager doesn't work when I use VisibleRegion in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-apps, markerclusterer

I'm creating my own icon marker in `ClusterManager` in `GoogleMap`. 
I hide the Google Marker with:

```
 item.getMarker().setAlpha(Constants.MARKER_ALPHA_IS_INVISIBLE);
```

and in MarkerOptions, I set the alpha to 1. 
Unfortunately, when I try to hide a marker in map or delete it from the Cluster, the position of cluster in map breaks. For example, I have a marker in Berlin and the markers are well clustered, but when I zoom `GoogleMap`, this cluster goes to Russia.

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(item.getMarker().getTitle()));
    Bitmap markerBitmap = item.getBitmap();
    BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap);
    markerOptions.icon(bitmapDescriptor);
    markerOptions.getIcon().zzvg();
    markerOptions.alpha(Constants.MARKER_ALPHA_IS_VISIBLE);
    item.getMarker().setAlpha(Constants.MARKER_ALPHA_IS_INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the alpha stuff from?